# Unity Launcher 'Background' Will not Auto-Hide With Launcher Icons

Tags: unity, graphics, launcher

I recently set my Unity Launcher bar to auto-hide, and to be transparent, using the Compiz Configuration tools (ccsm, in the terminal). I did not use 'Unsettings' to do this, as, for whatever reason, it could not render my launcher transparent in the least. While the launcher auto-hides properly, in accordance with my settings, it has left behind a large, colored bar (the same size as the launcher) in its place. This bar does not go away at any time, except for when a window is dragged across it, at which point it disappears entirely, around the window, and reappears when the window has left its premise.

I am trying to rid myself of this colored bar; changing the desktop background has not fixed it, and logging out and logging back in has not fixed it either.

Answer (score 0):

unity --reset should reset your unity configuration if you're on 12.04 or earlier release.  Not sure what the command is for 12.10.

As an alternative to ccsm - which is not a bad program but seems to cause problems for some people - the MyUnity app is available from Software Center and will let you change the launcher behavior including auto-hide and transparency.